# "Будь ласка" при зверненні до кількох осіб

Tags: розмовна-українська

"Будь ласка" при зверненні до кількох осіб?

***Будь ласка (будьте ласкавi) виправляйте мої помилки, якщо я пишу українською***

*Це і приклад, і реальне прохання*

А як для ввічливій форми?

Comment: Чим не влаштовує _будьте ласкаві_?

Comment: @stegetsj А я знаю?

Comment: Які ви злі )))) Навіщо питання-то мінусувати?!

Comment: По-моєму, питання дуже корисне. Є подібне запитання англійською — [«plural for “будь ласка”»](/q/5784) — але питання різними мовами, наскільки я пам'ятаю, у нас вирішили не вважати дублікатами.

Comment: @Sasha *Є подібне запитання англійською* - А, дякую. Не бачив.

Comment: У жодному разі, будь ласка, не сприймайте це як докір (якщо чесно, то на мій погляд у нас склалася погала традиція відразу висувати надто жорсткі вимоги до запитань/відповідей — і це відлякує нових учасників — але вже маємо, що маємо…).

Comment: @Sasha Це зайве. Я прийшов сюди з росiйскомовного ресурса SE, де брав участь з 2012-го року. Так шо всьо до "традицiй" розумiю - i ще вам можу пояснити. На жаль, розмовна українська в мене нiяка, Ось тут, може шо и зрозумiю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«Будь ласка» можна вживати і при звертанні до однієї особи, і при звертанні до кількох/багатьох осіб (тобто і з «ти», і з «ви» в прямому значенні, і з ввічливим «ви»).

Як я розумію, «будь ласка» (усупереч поширеній думці) насправді походить не від «будь ласкавий»/«будьте ласкаві», а від «будь твоя ласка»/«будь ваша ласка» (порівняйте: «будь моя воля, я би…»).

Утім, «будь ласкавий»/«будьте ласкаві» теж широко вживаються (паралельно з «будь ласка»).

Comment: *Як я розумію, «будь ласка» (усупереч поширеній думці) насправді походить не від «будь ласкавий»/«будьте ласкаві»,* - !!!! Ось воно шо! Дюже дякую.